# update value in config file dynamically

Tags: unix, ksh

I have a pipe delimited config file that looks like

```
  Value1|1
  Value2|2
  Value3|3
```

I am using grep command to get the line i want from the config file and this returns 2 as expected.

```
  grep 'Value2' config.ctl>config_tmp.ctl
  val=$(cut -f2,2 -d"|" config_tmp.ctl)
```

What i am trying to do is update the second column based on the first column

```
  Value2|2
```

to

```
  Value2|4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me on Linux with GNU sed version 4.1.5

```
sed -i '/^Value2|/s/^\(..*\)|.*$/\1|4/' config.ctl
```

The `-i` tells sed to directly edit the file.  You can add a suffix and it will create a backup of the original with that suffix, ex: `-i.bak` would create a copy called config.ctl.bak.

The rest of the syntax:

`/^value2|/` = only apply to lines that match this regex, the `^` means begining of the line, and the `|` is a literal, this way you don't match things that are similar such as `Value22|22`.

The rest of the line does a substitution only on those lines that matched Value2, the `\(` and `\)` pairs allow you to substitute in those matched values on the replace.

`^\(..*\)|` would match one or more characters at the beginning of the line up to the `|` symbol, `.*$` will match zero or more characters after the `|` symbol to the end of the line.  `$` represents the end of the line.  This should match the entire line.

The replace portion `/\1|4/` then replaces the line with what was matched inside the parenthesis followed by the `|` symbol followed by the number 4.

---

**Update 20170314**

If you do not have GNU sed with the -i option you can try something like this:

```
cp config.ctl config_tmp.ctl
sed '/^Value2|/s/^\(..*\)|.*$/\1|4/' config_tmp.ctl > config.ctl
```

Comment: So i don't have the -i option. So i should do something like sed /^Value2|/s/^\(..*\)|.*$/\1|4/' config.ctl.tmp then just mv config.ctl.tmp config.ctl

Comment: @user3753693 Updated with example not using -i option.

Comment: If you don't have `-i` in `sed` you may find you do in `perl` E.g. `perl -i.bak -p '/^Value2|/ && s/^\(..*\)|.*$/\1|4/' config.ctl`

Comment: @WalterA thank you for removing the `-i` in my example missed removing it when i pasted the original sed command.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the next variables set (or get them with `read -p "Key please:" key`)

```
key="Value2"
newvalue="4"
```

With gnu `sed` you can do

```
sed -i 's/\('"${key}"'|\).*/\1'"${newvalue}"'/' config.ctl
```

Without the `-i` option you should redirect it to a tmp-file and move it when `sed` succeeds.
That will be easier than `vi` in a here document.
An alternative is the good old `ed`.

```
ed -s config.ctl << EOF
1,$ s/^${key}|.*/${key}|${value}/
w
q
EOF
```

Warning: Both answers will give problems when the key or value have slashes.